# How do I identify the name of disk in first slot of my server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, diskmanagement, lenovo

I have 16 disks inserted into Lenovo SR650. The disk names /dev/sda , /dev/sdb ... are not in order with its position in the slots. I want to identify what is the name of the disk in first slot in Ubuntu16.04.4 commandline.

Comment: [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/121763/3150) on U&L gives a generic way of doing it via groking serial numbers, but I'm sure there's a more efficient manner of doing it.

Answer (score 5):

Disks are enumerated by path under `/dev/disk/by-path/` and via WWN under `/dev/disk/by-id/`. The first tell you about slot number and, by matching it with WWN, enable you to determine how slot enumeration is layed down (ie: from left to right and bottom to up, or vice versa). Most servers even have the slot themselves numbered (but be warned: I saw occasions where the printed number did not match `/dev/disk/by-path`).

Assuming you have no SN/WWN information on the disks themselves, you can use LED information to identify the disks:

- if your enclosure is supported, you can use something as `ledctl` to let the disk/slot blink;
- if you can't use `ledctl` or similar, you can generate a read load for each disk by running, in a fast loop, something as `smartctl --all /dev/disk/by-path/<disk>` while watching your disk/slot led.

Answer (score 0):

Try the command:

> blkid

Here's a link to more info: 
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/s2-sysinfo-filesystems-blkid

Comment: This doesn't tell you which bay a disk is installed in.